# Returning a Location header in a 201 Created response in Liberator

Tags: clojure, liberator

I'm trying to implement a collection resource with Liberator where a `POST` request to the collection URL (e.g. `/posts`) would create a new blog post item. That's working fine. What is not working is responding to the `POST` request with a `201 Created` response including a `Location` header pointing to the new URL (e.g. `/posts/1`).

I can either respond with a `201 Created`, but then I'm not able to include the `Location` header response, and hence the client won't know what the new URL is, or alternatively I can set `:post-redirect? true`, and return a `303 See Other` response with a `Location` header.

Is there any way to return a `201 Created` *and* the `Location` header from a Liberator POST handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every handler can return a full ring response including headers by using ring-response:

```
(defresource baz
  :method-allowed? true
  :new? true
  :exists? true
  :post! (fn [ctx] {::location "http://example.com"})
  :post-redirect? false 
  :handle-created (fn [{l ::location }] 
                    (ring-response {:headers {"Location" l}}))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, i like the separation between :post! and :handle-created. But the binding form in :handle-created should be (fn [{l ::location}] …) to compile correctly

Comment: Returning `{:headers {"Location" "/test"}}` from `:handle-created` fn renders an HTML table body with the word "headers", instead of redirecting.

Comment: @pate, thanks for the comment, you actually need to wrap the response in ring-response to for the interpretation as a ring response